# calling other module with async await

Tags: node.js

Im developing a web app using node js server. I stuck in a place which is i'm going to get some data from some other module. It doesn't work well. Here is the code.

Beginning of the Dashboard.js, I wrote this.

```
var auth = require('./auth');
```

Dashboard.js API

```
.get('/getAllResturants', async function (req, res, next) {

        console.log('LOCATION A 001');
        var testValue = await auth.testCalling(2);
        console.log('LOCATION A 002');       
        console.log(testValue);
        console.log('LOCATION A 003');

        global.restaurant.findAll().then(restaurant => {
            console.log('LOCATION A 004');
            res.json(restaurant);            
        });       

    })
```

auth.js file

```
module.exports = {

    testCalling: async function (id) {
        console.log('LOCATION B 001');
         global.restaurant.findOne({
            where: { id: id }
        }).then(function (record) {
            console.log('LOCATION B 002');          
            return record;
        });
    },

};
```

simply **testValue** doesn't have any value. (What I need is to get a value from it and according to the value, process further.) testValue shows in the log as *undefined*. Also when executing, logs shows like below. I used async, await for the program and seems it doesn't work properly.

```
LOCATION A 001
LOCATION B 001
LOCATION A 002
undefined
LOCATION A 003
LOCATION B 002
LOCATION A 004
```

Please give me a direction to find the issue in this programe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are not figure out the [async/await function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Await must be a promise. I gives you an example.

```js
const sleep = time => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(true), time)
});

async function run(time) {
  console.log('---start---');
  const bool = await sleep(time);
  console.log(`---end ${bool}---`);
}

run(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise from the `findOne` call:

```
module.exports = {

    testCalling: async function (id) {
        console.log('LOCATION B 001');
        return global.restaurant.findOne({
            where: { id: id }
        }).then(function (record) {
            console.log('LOCATION B 002');          
            return record;
        });
    },

};
```

Without that `return` the function falls back to the default return value of `undefined`.